# MySQL Master-Slave replication on Windows, when put server-id=1 on master it's not starting

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I am trying to get Master to Slave replication on my MySQL server, but after put in server-id=1 in the `my.conf` and stop the mysql server and then start it again from Services in windows it's getting error and could not start.

Problem is that i can not find a real error message, the only one i get is from windows that could not start the service.

Do anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have trouble starting the MySQL service, check its error log.  On Windows, it's probably located in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server x.y.z\data\computername.err`  (where *computername* is the name of your Windows server).

A couple of ideas:  try spelling the config variable "server_id" with an underscore instead of a dash.  They are supposed to be interchangeable, but I have seen cases where they aren't for specific variables.

Search the config file to see if you have another line declaring a different server-id.

Did you make any other changes to the config file at the same time?  If so, it could be that the server-id change is fine, but another change resulted in an error.  Undo those changes and make them one at a time, restarting the MySQL service each time.

Comment: Big thanks! when i writeing server_id=1 then it works! I running MySQL Server 5.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 for refrence

Comment: I'm glad the suggestion helped.  It's just one of those weird inconsistencies.